# Spin verification error

Tags: verification, spin

I've created a model in Spin. The simulation is running as expected. However, when I try to verify ltl properties, I get the following results:

```
C:/cygwin64/bin/gcc.exe -DMEMLIM=1024 -O2 -DXUSAFE -w -o pan pan.c
./pan -m10000  -a
Pid: 9372
pan:1: VECTORSZ is too small, edit pan.h (at depth 0)
pan: wrote cs.pml.trail

(Spin Version 6.4.5 -- 1 January 2016)
Warning: Search not completed
    + Partial Order Reduction

Full statespace search for:
    never claim             + (p1)
    assertion violations    + (if within scope of claim)
    acceptance   cycles     + (fairness disabled)
    invalid end states  - (disabled by never claim)

State-vector 1036 byte, depth reached 0, errors: 1
        0 states, stored
        0 states, matched
        0 transitions (= stored+matched)
        0 atomic steps
hash conflicts:         0 (resolved)

Stats on memory usage (in Megabytes):
    0.000   equivalent memory usage for states (stored*(State-vector + overhead))
    0.000   actual memory usage for states (less than 1k)
  128.000   memory used for hash table (-w24)
    0.534   memory used for DFS stack (-m10000)
    0.632   total actual memory usage



pan: elapsed time 4.11e+03 seconds
To replay the error-trail, goto Simulate/Replay and select "Run"
```

Running the simulation using the trail file didn't give much information since the simulation ends immediately (I only get warnings related to unused variables). I suspect that `VECTORSZ is too small` is causing the issue. How do I change this value using iSpin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I was able to fix the problem.

Using iSpin, go to `Verification` tab, then click `Show Advanced Parameter Settings`. Then add `-DVECTORSZ=4096` to the `Extra Compile-Time Directives` field and then re-run verification.